# How to insert a paragraph and table inside a named tag field?

Tags: c#, ms-word, interop

I try to fill a MS Word-Template using C# Word Interop. In the .dotx file I want to fill a named tag (or named field or what you call it). I am able to append the text and table at the end of my document but not inside the named field. Could someone point me to the right direction?

This is working at the end of the document:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = app.Documents.Open(WORDTEMPLATE);

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraph para1 = doc.Content.Paragraphs.Add();
para1.Range.Text = "Hello World";
para1.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Table firstTable = doc.Tables.Add(para1.Range, 5, 5);
firstTable.Borders.Enable = 1;

foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Row row in firstTable.Rows)
{
    foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Cell cell in row.Cells)
    {
         //Header row  
         if (cell.RowIndex == 1)
         {
             cell.Range.Text = "Column " + cell.ColumnIndex.ToString();
             cell.Range.Font.Bold = 1;
             //other format properties goes here  
             cell.Range.Font.Name = "verdana";
             cell.Range.Font.Size = 10;
             //cell.Range.Font.ColorIndex = WdColorIndex.wdGray25;                              
             cell.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdColor.wdColorGray25;
             //Center alignment for the Header cells  
             cell.VerticalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdCellVerticalAlignment.wdCellAlignVerticalCenter;
             cell.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphCenter;

         }
         //Data row  
         else
         {
             cell.Range.Text = (cell.RowIndex - 2 + cell.ColumnIndex).ToString();
         }
    }
}

doc.SaveAs2(RESULTFILE, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatDocumentDefault);
doc.Close(false);
app.Quit(false);
```

And what I want is something like this:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = app.Documents.Open(WORDTEMPLATE);

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range range = doc.SelectContentControlsByTag("MyTagName")[1].Range; // !! this line is working

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraph para1 = doc.Content.Paragraphs.Add(range); // !! this line is not working
para1.Range.Text = "Hello World";
para1.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Table firstTable = doc.Tables.Add(para1.Range, 5, 5);
firstTable.Borders.Enable = 1;

foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Row row in firstTable.Rows)
{
    foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Cell cell in row.Cells)
    {
         //Header row  
         if (cell.RowIndex == 1)
         {
             cell.Range.Text = "Column " + cell.ColumnIndex.ToString();
             cell.Range.Font.Bold = 1;
             //other format properties goes here  
             cell.Range.Font.Name = "verdana";
             cell.Range.Font.Size = 10;
             //cell.Range.Font.ColorIndex = WdColorIndex.wdGray25;                              
             cell.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdColor.wdColorGray25;
             //Center alignment for the Header cells  
             cell.VerticalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdCellVerticalAlignment.wdCellAlignVerticalCenter;
             cell.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphCenter;

         }
         //Data row  
         else
         {
             cell.Range.Text = (cell.RowIndex - 2 + cell.ColumnIndex).ToString();
         }
    }
}

doc.SaveAs2(RESULTFILE, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatDocumentDefault);
doc.Close(false);
app.Quit(false);
```

Thanks!

Comment: I do not know C#. However, I see nothing in your code that adds any field or content control. I think what you want is a rich text content control. Look at John Korchok's page on inserting Content Controls with vba: http://www.brandwares.com/bestpractices/2019/08/content-controls-for-macos-cool-code/

Comment: @CharlesKenyon The field is already in my Word template. So I want to fill my content into that field. I can select the field's range by `doc.SelectContentControlsByTag("MyTagName")[1].Range` Then I'm able to fill text into my field. But I want fo fill in a table too, thats not working. Because to create a table I need to provide a range and I don't know how to get that correct range.

Comment: In Word parlance, you are using a Content Control (which is good), not a field. You should be able to insert your table inside that range. I am assuming the Content Control is a Rich Text Content Control, not a Plain Text CC.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use a variable name of "range" because that is a reserved word in the application. Change to this

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range rng = doc.SelectContentControlsByTag("MyTagName")[1].Range;
```

and then follow with

```
rng.text = "Hello World";
```

Comment: range is a local variable. `range.text = "Hello World";` is working as excpected. But I want to fill in text and a table.